Eclipse not showing run as TestNG
I have added testng dependencies in pom.xml and also added external testng jar, but still it is not showing run as testng.
IN testNG.org there is no dependencies to download. the external eclipse dependencies showing no url
can anyone help me wit the new testng dependencies
